# Issue renaming directories

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, file-rename

I want to rename directories of those whose checkbox has been checked by the user with a single click of the `Update` button. The textbox and checkbox values are collected in an array and sent to the server via jQuery. Firebug shows the correct array values being passed. The problem is that it renames the first checked directory to `Array` rather than to the new value inputted in the textbox while the other values remain unchanged.

What am I doing wrong in this code?:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="album_text[]" id="album_text" class="album_text"  />
<input type="text" name="album_text[]" id="album_text" class="album_text"   />
<input type="text" name="album_text[]" id="album_text" class="album_text"  />

<input name="album_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="album_checkbox" value="' . $res. '">
<input name="album_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="album_checkbox" value="' . $res. '">
```

JQUERY:

```
  $("#album_update").click(function() {
                var album_name = new Array();


                $("input[@name='album_checkbox[]']:checked").each(function() {
                    album_name.push($(this).val());
                });

                var album_text= new Array();

                $("input[name='album_text[]']").each(function(){

                    if( $(this).val() ) {
                            album_text.push($(this).val());
                    }

                });  



             var postData = { 
                        "album_name" : album_name,
                        "album_text" : album_text,
                        "album_update" : $("#album_update").val()
                };   


                      //make the call
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "updalbums.php",
                        data: postData, 
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data){
                            alert("updated");
                        }
                      });
        });
```

PHP:

```
public function updateAlbum() {

                if (isset($_POST['album_text']) && isset($_POST['album_name'])) {

                    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/';

                    foreach ($_POST['album_name'] as $albums_name ) {
                        $album_text = $_POST['album_text'];
                        rename($path.$albums_name, $path.$album_text); 
                    }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$album_text is an array because you are drawing straight from the $_POST global $_POST['album_text'], which is an array.  You need to identify the correct index.

You could access the index like below but it seems like it would be prone to breaking.

```
                    foreach ($_POST['album_name'] as $idx => $albums_name ) {
                    $album_text = $_POST['album_text'][$idx];
                    rename($path.$albums_name, $path.$album_text); 
                }
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it! But can you please explain what do you mean by `but it seems like it would be prone to breaking`?

Comment: @fuz3d @josh I wouldn't worry about this breaking, I would worry that using this code as is, anyone could move *anything* *anywhere*. Like `rename('index.php', '/tmp/delete_me.txt')`. This is **beyond stupidity**

Comment: @adlawson, I know this code has security holes but I am still learning and would definitely appreciate your pointers on adding the security layer once I post this code for review on the codereview site.

Comment: It would be prone to breaking because you are relying the indexes matching up.  99% of the time this would probably be the case, but if a checkbox or textbox went missing or was intentionally moved it would break things, most likely skew your file names.  Your indexes should be keyed with a unique id.  Also, you really should not look at a security layer as an add on to be addressed later.  It makes it easy to overlook things.

@adlawson, Yes, there are glaring security holes in the script, that wasn't the question asked, but you are right bring it up.

Comment: @Josh, you're right about security. As for unique ids, the texboxes and the checkboxes are generated dynamically at runtime.